# Upload an Attachment/Document through REST API

Tags: javascript, rest-api

I am following [these instructions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index_Left.htm#CSHID=dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fdome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp), but I keep getting the error

`[{"message":"MediaType of ''multipart/form-data' is not supported by this resource","errorCode":"UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE"}]`

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Can you post some code? Are you creating an Attachment or a Document

Comment: The url for an Attachment is like: https:[instance].salesforce.com/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/Attachment/

Comment: You may find this handy: http://yuanmengblog.blogspot.co.nz/2014/01/use-forcecom-rest-api-to-upload.html

Comment: after a few trail & errors . I figured it out

Comment: That linked helped me too. Thanks for posting it . Here is the updated  Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=boundary_string_1414605653846

Comment: @kumaro - please write an answer so that others can easily see it - you'll be able to accept it in a few hours